# Xcode full stack trace

Tags: xcode, stack-trace

While debugging is there anyway to see a complete stack trace (i.e., a list of methods called in the main thread) on the command window?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C - getting line number or full stack trace from debugger error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501358/objective-c-getting-line-number-or-full-stack-trace-from-debugger-error)

Comment: Programmatically, you can use callStackSymbols as Mihir describes.  But of course you can also stop in Xcode, at a breakpoint (or just pressing "pause") and examine the stack in the left-hand column.  (Always enable an exception breakpoint.)

Comment: (+1 for realizing that examining the stack is important.  Far too few folks starting out on Xcode appreciate this.)

Comment: I am doing same, but in stack trace I can see just 5 or 6 method calls and after that on 25 its UIApplicationMain and on 26 its main. I can't see the methods between 6 and 25. I want to see complete stack trace.

Comment: I got it via nslog. thanks guys

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can print the stack trace in the NSLog by

```
NSLog(@"Stack trace : %@",[NSThread callStackSymbols]);
```

Upon a crash, next to the word `(lldb)`, you can type:

```
po [NSThread callStackSymbols]
```

**Edit:**

For better output on console on Swift you can use following line instead:

```
Thread.callStackSymbols.forEach{print($0)}
```

Comment: within lldb it can be printed with: po [NSThread callStackSymbols]

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: po Thread.callStackSymbols returns `cannot use dot operator on a type`

Answer (score 166):

Use the `bt` command in (lldb).

Once paused or after a crash, just type `bt` into the debug console.
It will print the full stack trace.

[image: sample output of bt command]

Comment: Awesome tip for tracking down a constraint issue after setting the symbolic breakpoint.

Comment: You can also mention the thread id (from the debug pane) for capturing stack of that particular thread. For example, in case of Thread 42, you'd do - "bt 42"

Comment: Be patient as it took about 30 seconds for it to print out

Answer (score 72):

In Xcode 6 you can click the button at the bottom left corner of the pane which shows the full stack trace.
[image: Xcode 6 show full stack trace]

Comment: This answer is still current in Xcode 11, but the button has been moved slightly. ;)

Answer (score 17):

In Xcode 5 you can move the slider at the bottom of the pane which shows the stack trace. It controls how much of the struck trace is shown.

[image: Slider controlling the stack trace]

Comment: How do you do this in Xcode 6?  There is no slider anymore.

Comment: This slider appears to have been removed in XCode6... if anyone knows how to do this under XCode6 you would be my hero.

Comment: @Steazy See Gong Pengjun's answer for Xcode 6-11 (or possibly later, 11.x is current at this moment)

Answer (score 4):

You can add `breakpoint` before exception is thrown. First go to `Breakpoint Navigator` (cmd + 6). In the bottom left corner mouse click plus button. OR
You can use `Instruments` (/Developer/Applications/Instruments) to help detect usage of `zombie` `objects`.
 [Reference](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/02/cocoa-tutorial-fixing-memory-leaks-with-instruments/)

And When you add breakpoint review the picture will create by `Xcode`.

[image]

You can expand the stack trace using the slider at bottom use `step over` and `over` for line by line logs.

thanks hope this will help you