# XCode 'NSLog is not a valid command'?

Tags: xcode

I am trying to get the full stack trace by using the solution here: 
[Xcode full stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946499/xcode-full-stack-trace)

But I keep getting the following error:

```
(lldb) NSLog(@"Stack trace : %@",[NSThread callStackSymbols])
error: 'NSLog' is not a valid command.
error: Unrecognized command 'NSLog(@Stack trace : %@,[NSThread'.
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In (lldb), you can try `bt` command. `NSLog` is for Objective-C code.

Comment: Yeah I am writing c++, but do you have a full command for that?

Comment: @Goldname As I know, in your Xcode console (i.e. lldb), you can input `bt` to get the stack trace of current thread (where your break point hit), and also you can input `bt all` to print stack trace of all threads. I think it is same for C++ or Objective-C as both are compiled by Apple's LLVM.