# How to copy all thread backtraces when debugger is paused in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

When I'm running an iOS app via Xcode's debugger and I pause execution, I can see all the threads and their stack traces in the Debug navigator on the left side. How can I copy all threads and all of their backtraces into my clipboard so I can send it to someone?

I'm on Xcode 9.2.

Answer (score 10):

In lldb debug pane run `bt all`, then copy the output (found buried in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946499/xcode-full-stack-trace#comment52485983_26770913)). If there's other console output, it helps to first click the "Clear the Console" button on the bottom first so you can then Cmd+A,Cmd+C to select all and copy the output.

I'm writing a separate question and answer from the original for searchability.